# What would be the right SQL statement to select all records for the latest day IGNORING time stamp?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySql Table with the following data

```
cent_id |     datetime      |    NO 
1094    |2020-03-08 12:00:00|   5.160   
1093    |2020-03-08 11:00:00|   10.539
1092    |2020-03-08 10:00:00|   18.568  
1091    |2020-03-08 09:00:00|   29.630  
1090    |2020-03-08 08:00:00|   29.912  
1089    |2020-03-08 07:00:00|   26.893  
1088    |2020-03-08 06:00:00|   16.270  
1087    |2020-03-08 05:00:00|   29.653  
1086    |2020-03-07 04:00:00|   0.000   
1085    |2020-03-07 03:00:00|   0.547   
1084    |2020-03-07 02:00:00|   -0.217  
1083    |2020-03-07 01:00:00|   -0.095  
1082    |2020-03-07 00:00:00|   -0.095  
1081    |2020-03-07 23:00:00|   -0.082
```

I want to select  all records for the latest date ( in this case 2020-03-08 ) ignoring the timestamp using PHP.

I have tried:

```
SELECT MAX( DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%W %M %Y')) AS datetime, cent_id, no 
FROM tablename
```

but it only returns one record which is latest based on both date and timestamp. My desired results would be

```
1094    2020-03-08 12:00:00 5.160   
1093    2020-03-08 11:00:00 10.539  
1092    2020-03-08 10:00:00 18.568  
1091    2020-03-08 09:00:00 29.630  
1090    2020-03-08 08:00:00 29.912  
1089    2020-03-08 07:00:00 26.893  
1088    2020-03-08 06:00:00 16.270  
1087    2020-03-08 05:00:00 29.653
```

This should be true for the latest date in the table i.e it could be 2020-03-09 etc.

New to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's possible, maybe change that data into two separate columns and work with that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `date()` function in the `where` clause to get only the date part of the timestamp:

```
select * from tablename
where date(datetime) = (select max(date(datetime)) from tablename)
```

or:

```
select * from tablename
where datetime >= (select max(date(datetime)) from tablename)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e73a0a26538bd70f1149c86b23dad6a8).
Results:

```
> cent_id | datetime            |     NO
> ------: | :------------------ | -----:
>    1094 | 2020-03-08 12:00:00 |   5.16
>    1093 | 2020-03-08 11:00:00 | 10.539
>    1092 | 2020-03-08 10:00:00 | 18.568
>    1091 | 2020-03-08 09:00:00 |  29.63
>    1090 | 2020-03-08 08:00:00 | 29.912
>    1089 | 2020-03-08 07:00:00 | 26.893
>    1088 | 2020-03-08 06:00:00 |  16.27
>    1087 | 2020-03-08 05:00:00 | 29.653
```